# Error: "is already declared as protected WithEvents"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Web Controls

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtUsername" runat="server" CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" type="text" required></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox id="txtPassword" runat="server" CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" type="password" required></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage
Protected WithEvents txtUsername As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
Protected WithEvents txtPassword As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal
```

Error:

> Parse Error: 'txtPassword' is already declared as 'Protected WithEvents txtPassword As System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.TextBox in' this class 
>           'txtUsername' is already declared as 'Protected WithEvents txtUsername As System.Web.UI.Webcontrols.TextBox in' this class

What could be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is 3 years late, but I've just solved this problem and I'll share my solution to help out anyone stumbling here.

I got this error when I commented out a control, worked on other parts of the project, then uncommented it.

Simply change the ID of your control in your aspx and aspx.vb and the error will be gone.

```
<!-- changed from txt to text -->
<asp:TextBox id="textUsername" runat="server" CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" type="text" required></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox id="textPassword" runat="server" CssClass="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" type="password" required></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: This answer may eliminate the error message but it may not actually fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add controls to the aspx page your controls are added to the partial class of the same name as your code behind file. If you add then again to the code file you will get the error.

Comment: But, removing those gave me another error "Control 'txtUsername' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." I'm sure it's inside a form with runat=server

Answer (score 0):

You may have two or more Web Forms with the same class name.

Contents of **somepage.aspx** and **anotherpage.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page ... Inherits="somepage" %>
...
```

Contents of **somepage.aspx.vb** and **anotherpage.aspx.vb**:

```
Partial Class somepage
    ...
End Class
```

In the sample code above, changing the `Inherits` attribute and class name in the **anotherpage.*** files to `anotherpage` fixes the problem. The code-behind looks a little different if you are using C#, but it's the same idea.